# How can I setup my computer to allow a computer on a network to access a server on the company network while I am connected through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I work remotely and I access the company network trough VPN. I have another computer that that I use but does not have a VPN connection. I want to use my computer with VPN to allow traffic from the computer without VPN to access my company's network. Any idea?

Comment: Here’s an idea: check with your company’s IT department, because they (a) might know the best answer, and/or (b) might emphatically tell you not to try this, because they have a rule against it.

Comment: Agree with G-man here. This is almost certainly going to be against company policy and could get you in trouble.